# Trace form and totally real number fields

Tags: reference-request, quadratic-forms, field-trace

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}}$
Let $K$ be a number field then there is a quadratic form over the $\Q$ vector space $K$ given by
$$\tau: K\rightarrow  \Q \qquad y\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}_{K/\Q}(y^2)$$
which is also known as the trace-form of $K$. As far as I can recall, the trace form is positive definite iff $K$ is totally real. Where can I find the proof of this statement? Or is it rather trivial to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensoring up with $\Bbb R$, the trace form extends to a real quadratic form
on $K\otimes\Bbb R$, given by the same formula. We have the usual decomposition $K\otimes\Bbb R\cong \Bbb R^{r_1}\oplus\Bbb C^{r_2}$
as $\Bbb R$-algebras. If there is a copy of $\Bbb C$ present, then on this
the trace form is $z\mapsto z^2+\overline z^2$ which takes positive, negative and zero values, so is indefinite.

Comment: So this is one direction, is the other direction trivial? How do I see that the trace form is given by the map $z\mapsto z^2 + \bar z^2$ ?